# Communication between two submodules

Tags: android, git-submodules

I've a service called `SecretService.java` which is located `/project/../submodule1/src/main/java/com/..`
And I've a manager called `AwesomeManager.java` which is located in `/project/../submodule2/src/main/java/com/..`

How can I create some kind of callback/listeners to make a communication between submodules? Is this even possible?

Maybe somehow with broadcasts? Could someone show me an implementation of that, please?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to pass data between different modules of same apps like inner library module to main app module's class...something like this.

Lets consider you want to send data from inner module's some class to outer modules "MainActivity" class.

To obtain this you need to define complete package name inside AndroidManifest.xml file in main module like below,

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.outerPackage.activity.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/NoActionBarLight" />
```

And after that you can call intent to go to MainActivity of outer module like below,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Class.forName("com.example.outerPackage.activity.MainActivity"));
```

So with full class name's trick you can obtain your desired result.